# Apache URL Mapping

Tags: apache, ssl, https

i have setup apache for ssl.
i can browse `https://localhost`

I would like to change `https://localhosz` to `https://www.test.com` or whatever

My httpd-ssl.conf:

```
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/logsssl_scache(512000)"
SSLEngine on  
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/TeamPass" 
ServerName localhos:443 
ErrorLog "C:/wamp/logs/mysecuresite_error_log" 
TransferLog "C:/wamp/logs/mysecuresite_access_log"
SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/webserver.cer" 
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/private.key"  

CustomLog "C:/wamp/logs/ssl_request_log" \ "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
```

How do I have to change my config file so that apache will start because i tried some configuration with virtualhost but wamp wouldn't start after changes has been made.
This is a testserver so i have no DNS Server but have edit my host file.

I need C:/wamp/www/TeamPass to listen to test.com:443, i could change servername to this url but i'm not sure if this is the right way.
What would i have to do to use url `https://pass.test.de`, do i need to use rewrite module

Comment: change your hostname to www.test.com and localhost in the virtualhost to the same

Comment: changing ServerName localhos:443 to ServerName pass.test.de:443 also would work. Document Root links to my Site. But this config wouldn't work for multisites because all other sites would run under pass.test.de/phpmyadmin for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS Windows, you can modify the file **httpd-vhosts.conf** located on the folders **conf/extra/** inside Apache's instalation path, to include the next configuration:

```
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
  ServerName www.test.com
  DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\TeamPass"
  <Directory "C:\wamp\www\TeamPass">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog "C:\wamp\logs\mysecuresite_error_log"
  CustomLog "C:\wamp\logs\ssl_request_log" \ "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "C:\wamp\OpenSSL\certs\webserver.cer" 
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\wamp\OpenSSL\certs\private.key" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, in the file **C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts** add this line at the end:

```
127.0.0.1   www.test.com
```

Comment: So i still need to keep my config in httpd-ssl.conf? And activate include httpd-vhosts.conf in http.conf?

Comment: I guess not, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Also, check for this line to be uncommented in conf\httpd.conf: `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: Yes thats what i meant with activate include httpd-vhosts.conf in http.conf? But when i active this modul wamp won't start because something is wrong with config in httpd-vhosts. I have also seen httpd-ssl.config where this is keept in ssl.config file. I still can change url by changing the default vhost in my first config. So thats a first step :)

Comment: Try commenting all the content in httpd-vhosts.conf, and add just the new configuration.

Comment: I replaced hole config with yours and added sessioncache because there was an error this is missing but somehow my apache 2.4.2 dont like the config, even when i put it in httpd-ssl because this should also work. I guess is about something with the virtual host config

Comment: As last resource, don't include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in the httpd.conf file, and add this configuration to httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

change your hostname to www.test.com

```
edit or run the file hostname and the file hosts

sudo gksu gedit /etc/hostname  and add www.test.com

sudo gksu gedit /etc/hosts and add the line 127.0.0.1 www.test.com localhost 

in the virtualhoste use www.test.com instead of localhost.
```

Comment: sorry didn't mentioned that this is windows system

Comment: alright i'm using ubuntu , check how to modify the windows hosts file.